# Does Google Sign-In allow you to restrict which users get access to your app?

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, google-oauth

I want to add Google sign-in to an Android app using this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview

Does it allow me to restrict usage of the app to certain specific Gmail accounts? I.e. does it allow authorization? I don't mean creating an array of Gmail accounts in the app itself and using them in a "if contains" statement, I mean setting the allowable Gmails from the google cloud console itself. If it isn't possible with just Google sign-in, then how?